# Subset a list and run function on each subset and put results in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like so:

```
 df<- data.frame(plot=c(rep(133, 3), rep(134,4)), plant= c(1,1,2,3,3,4,4), 
 morpho= c("A", "B", "C", "D","E","B","C"), freq=c(2,1,2,1,3,1,3))
```

Then I use the following to get the dataframe in a format that is useable for `cast()`:

```
library("reshape")
cast<- cast(df, plot+plant ~ morpho, 
               value ='freq',fun.aggregate=sum)
```

which makes  it a list of 7 elements.

I now want to apply a function to the each plot to calculate beta diversity among plants in each plot. I would use the function :

```
library("vegetarian")
d(cast, lev="beta", q=1, boot=TRUE)
```

I tried the following without success:

```
 lapply(cast, function(x){d(x,lev= "beta", q=1, boot=TRUE)})
```

The output for this example would be:

```
 output<- data.frame( plot=c(133, 134), D.Value= c(2,2 ), StdErr=c(0, 1.734224e-16)  )
```

Comment: which package is the `cast` function from?

Comment: My apologies, I made the edit.

Comment: you are trying to compute beta diversity for each plot. looking at the cast data that seems to be rowwise yet lapply is for "columnwise" ie the lista of a dataframe are columnwise and not rowwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this by

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
split(cast[-(1:2)], cast$plot) %>%
        map(d, lev = "beta", q = 1, boot = TRUE) %>%
        map(as_tibble) %>% 
        bind_rows(., .id = 'plot')
```

---

If we look at the OP's code, it is looping through each column, where as `d` requires 'abundances' as (based on `?d`)

> Community data as a matrix where columns are individual species and
>   rows are sites. Matrix elements are abundance data

Therefore, we `split` the dataset by the 'plot' on the subset of data i.e. the data with only the count columns, apply the 'd' on each of the `list` elements by using `map` and then bind the list elements with `bind_rows`

Comment: I am getting the following error and cannot figure out why there is a problem with my real dataset. The only things that appear different in the real data frame are 1) 195 obs and 143 variables, the plot and plant are factors. `Error in apply(normalize.rows(abundances) * w, 2, sum) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length`/. Maybe because some plots have only one plant.

Comment: Never mind, that was this issue. I had on plot with only one plant and needed to remove that entry for your solution to work. Thanks!